Getting Access denied when users trying to access word or excel document on SharePoint Server Subscription Edition on-premises
We are on SharePoint Server Subscription edition on-premise. We are seeing "Access denied contact administrator" when users are trying to access word/excel files. when we checked logs I can see the below two errors
Handling access denied for non browser request. IsOAuth: 'False'.
403 Access denied.
We tried increasing the Distributed Cache resuesttime values and other values on DIstributed cache and rebooted the servers but nothing helped. The issue is intermittent which is hitting hard for us. Can any one suggest what could be issue and action that needs to be taken to resolve. Thank you!

It sounds tricky. Anything more you can say about the users affected by the issue? All of them? Only in a specific location? Specific devices? Specific type of user/ department? Only at specific times (weekend, 6pm)?
There are a few things you could try:

Check if OAuth authentication is properly configured and the Secure Token Service (STS) is functioning correctly.
Get-SPAuthenticationRealm

the App Management Service application

I assume you checked the Distributed Cache and restarted it (with "rebooted the servers")
Use-CacheCluster
Get-CacheHost
Stop-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance
Start-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance

If you're using a multi-server farm, ensure Distributed Cache is properly configured across all servers and that Request Management isn't misrouting tokens or requests inconsistently.

Check your Office Online Server:
https://powershellscripts.github.io/articles/en/Server/Office%20Online%20Server%20Troubleshooting%20in%20Sharepoint%20Environment/
(bunch of suggestions in the article, better and worse)

Check if clock synchronization between the SharePoint servers and Office clients is correct. If the clocks between servers and clients are not in sync, tokens may appear expired.

network firewalls or proxy configurations??



Its happening to all users but intermittent .
Checked OAuth and is good
checked App Managemtn Service App and is working
Distributed Cache service is checked and restarted and rebooted the servers as well
I will check Office online server
how to check clock synch between SP Server and Office client
there was a firewall change on last week then this weird stuff started

I found the below errors after doing verbose logs
WopiHiddenFrame: getTargetHelper: targetUrl is null for docx/Word and action PreloadView
GenerateWacUrl failed to produce a URL/actionEntry for docx, Word, en-US
any idea on these?
